# cleanest way to create multiple beans of the same class with different properties

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean, spring-properties

Say I have this properties file:

```
students.bill.firstname=John
students.bill.lastname=Doe
students.bill.age=20
students.jim.firstname=Jim
students.jim.lastname=Wright
students.jim.age=21
.
.
.
```

I want an xml bean that contains a map of students that has their firstname as the key.

Object example:

Student.java

```
public class Student {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    Integer age;
}
```

Classroom.java

```
public class Classroom {
    Map<String, Student> students;
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to maybe say, create a student bean from properties students.bill.* and add it to the classroom bean map. Then make one for students.jim.* and add it to the classroom bean map. I am really not wanting to create a bean for each student and go through and put each and every value in them.

Comment: I would go a straightforward way of doing what you mentioned "create a bean for each student", it is going to be very fast and simple to maintain.

Comment: The only bad thing about that is if I want to add a new property in the future I would have to add it in the properties and each bean rather than just the properties and maybe one template bean

Comment: Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames() and then parse the keys to extract all the values.

Comment: Say these are all global-session beans. How would I use propertyNames to initialize them? I'm new to spring. Where would I be doing this logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring already supports that out of the box, since Spring 0.9 (but not many people know about that).

You would need to modify your property file slightly.

```
student.(class)=your.package.here.Student
student.(abstract)=true

jim.(parent)=student
jim.firstname=Jim
jim.lastname=Wright
jim.age=21
... Other student based definitions here.
```

Now you can use a `BeanFactory` together with a [`PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader.html)

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory bf = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader reader = new PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader(bf);
reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("students.properties"));
Map<String, Student> students = bf.getBeansOfType(Student.class);
```

Now if you have a new student just add it to the properties file and reload.